# WCF Client on the same network not working

Tags: wcf, networking, client, duplex

I created a simple Chat app.
On the same computer everything working.
On the other computer on the same network it's not.

Here is the config file of the server:

```
        <service name="ChattingServer.ChattingService">
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9000/ChattingService "
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="ChattingServiceEndPoint"
                contract="ChattingInterfaces.Contract.IChattingService" />
        </service>
```

And this is the config file of the client:

```
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9000/ChattingService" binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="" contract="ChattingInterfaces.Contract.IChattingService"
            name="ChattingServiceEndPoint" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
    </client>
```

This on the same computer working just fine!

Now for the client on a different machine i changed the config file to this:

```
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://10.0.0.3:9000/ChattingService" binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="" contract="ChattingInterfaces.Contract.IChattingService"
            name="ChattingServiceEndPoint" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
    </client>
```

Changed just the ip.
I have ping back and forth, i shut down the firewall on both, no anti virus on both, both run win7 as admin, try with the name of the pc insted of the ip as well - not working.
The computers working on WiFi.

What can i do?
Thanx

Comment: Try using 10.0.0.3 everywhere instead of localhost. You may check if port is open by using telnet command: telnet 10.0.0.3 9000

Comment: Hey, I did what you said and no hope.
I checked on the host with netstat -an and i see that the port 9000 is on, i heaven saw that the other computer is listening (after i open the client on the remote pc) but when i do the telnet from the remote pc i get a blank screen with blinking white on the left top.
Looks like that there is a block of some sort.
What do y think?

Comment: If you see blank telnet port it means that port is open. So it looks fine.

Comment: Do you have any exceptions?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean exactly?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: I get imedetly the "ChattingClient has stpped working" windows can check online for solution..
and in the details in the "Problem signature" i see alot of information like "problem signature 01, 02, 03 .. 
Not really help..

Comment: Try to catch the exception that is thrown when making the service call.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.
The first method on the server is LogIn, i put a breakpoint in it, and its not stop there, that mean that it's not even get there, right?

Comment: So i did a try and catch in the client around the LogIn and i didn't catch a thing, so i copy the all solution to the client computer, and run only the client project in Debug, and when i trying to connect to the server i get the error "The server has rejected the client credentials".
can we call this a progress?